# How do you create a file without touching the hard disk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create PDFs that can be stored on an external server.

I do this:

```
    File.new("temp.pdf", "w").close
    File.open("temp.pdf", "wb") do |f|
        f.write(bytes)
    end
    File.open("temp.pdf", "r") do |f|
        # upload `f` to server
    end
    File.delete("temp.pdf")
```

then upload them to the server.

On my local machine this works fine, but, I recently tried running on another machine, and I got a permissions error in the log.

Is there a way to:

1. Write bytes to a file.
2. Never touch the hard disk.

Comment: I think you're jumping to conclusions here. What about fixing the root problem---the permissions error?

Comment: because I don't need to store the file on the machine. In my example, I create a file. and then delete it after it's uploaded. Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Isn't a file just a collection of bytes on a hard disk? Writing bytes without touching the hard disk is just keeping the data in memory, like your `bytes` variable. EDIT: Seems like you want to use some of the functionality of the `File` module without having an actual file, right?

Comment: is what what `f` is my block? o.o just bytes?

Comment: right. I need to create a PDF and send it elsewhere :)

Comment: Ruby's [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) class will let you create a file in memory. It's not good for huge files, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just upload the bytes to the server?

You may have to go a little lower-level than normal, but check for instance the `UploadIO` class of the `multipart-post` gem.

Comment: rewritten, from what I see UploadIO/multipart-post are like  request = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new("/path/", 
                                             { "file" => UploadIO.new(string_io, "text/plain", file.path), 
                                               "merge" => false, 
                                               "ignore_missing" => false, 
                                               "label" => "", 
                                               "low_priority" => false })
 so I would need to have a file that get passed to UploadIO

Comment: The args of the `UploadIO` constructor are: 1. an `IO` with your data, 2. a ContentType, 3. a string informing the supposed original path of the file (because the protocol expects a filename somewhere). As long as you have your data in an `IO` with the data, you can fake the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I have to write to file and delete the file since UploadIO takes in an open file
So I created an new file, wrote the content to it, passed it in as a File.open to UploadIO, and then deleted the file after I send it.